# Multiple flags wrong reason selected

Tags: bug, flags

I flagged a question as both off-topic and low-quality but upon click the flag once more the follow was displayed.

[image: Flags]

The image shows that the question was flagged as a duplicate.

Just to be sure I checked that I didn't click the wrong reason.

[image: Flags Selected]

**EDIT**

With the help of Martijn Pieters

The bug seems to be that VLQ Flag can be applied again after a different flag has been applied.

I believe that given the flags supplied all three options should be greyed out: duplicate; off-topic; VLQ.

Comment: Why are you flagging the question as both VLQ and off-topic?

Comment: This is [tag:status-by-design] see linked duplicate.

Comment: @Vogel612: the issue has evolved; the OP flagged the post as a VLQ first, and that option is not disabled.

Answer (score 0):

The image shows you already flagged the question as duplicate **or** off-topic. The two flag reasons together form one *type* of flag. The message underneath the two options reads:

> you have already raised **this type** of flag

You'd see the message on both options whenever you have picked one of the two.

It may be a limitation of the flagging dialog that just one type of flag raised is greyed out, however. You should not be able to flag as *very low quality* again now that you already flagged it as such. The off-topic flag may have come later, but it should not have re-enabled the *very low quality* flag option.

Comment: and I haven't raised a low-quality flag type?

Comment: @AshleyMedway: Yeah, that may be an issue. Presumably you cannot flag it for VLQ again?

Comment: No it says I have already flagged the question as low quality